# Using Variable on accessing the Form and Controls in MS Access

Tags: forms, variables, ms-access, controls

I have a MS Access project and I want to include some of data formatting. I already know how to do that formatting but having a lot of controls and form it's hard for me to retype my code and put the name of the active form and control.

Is it possible to set the current form and active controls on **Lost Focus** event?

I tried this code for formatting the `SettAmount` textbox and it works fine.

```
Dim varEnteredValue As Variant
varEnteredValue = Forms!dbfrmCrew.SubFrmCrew.Form.SettAmount.Value

If IsNumeric(varEnteredValue) = True Then
    Forms!dbfrmCrew.SubFrmCrew.Form.SettAmount.Format = "#,##0.00"
Else
    Forms!dbfrmCrew.SubFrmCrew.Form.SettAmount.Format = ">"
End If
```

I can get all the name of the form and controls for that function but I can't pass it to  variable

```
Dim ctlname, frmname, subfrmname As String

Public Function FormatValue() As Integer

If TypeName(Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl) = "SubForm" Then

ctlname = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Form.ActiveControl.Name
frmname = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
subfrmname = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name

Else
```

I tried this one getting the value of the control using a variable:

```
varEnteredValue = Forms!frmname.subfrmname.Form.ctlname.Value
```

But there's a error MS Access can't find the form 'frmname'.......

Hope anyone there can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use variables like the `Forms` collection

```
Dim nameOfForm as String
Dim frm as Form
nameOfForm = "MyFormName"
Set frm = Forms(NameOfForm)
```

or the `Controls` collection

```
Dim nameOfControl as String
Dim ctrl as Control
nameOfControl = "MyControlName"
Set ctrl = frm.Controls(nameOfControl)
```

You can get the name back by using `frm.Name` or `ctrl.Name`.

Note that you must use `Controls` with respect to a specific `Form` and the only forms loaded into `Forms` are forms which are actively loaded. This includes forms in design view. These forms open in design view might not have all their properties accessible.

To follow up on your edit:

You're trying to use your string of the form's name as a form object itself. You need to call the item in the `Forms` collection (which are stored by name)

```
varEnteredValue = Forms(frmname).Controls(subfrmname).Form.Controls(ctlname).Value
```

it would be more safe though to check for each of these existing before using them in a big long chain like that. Something like:

```
Dim mainForm as Form
Dim yourSubForm as Subform
Dim yourControl as Control

On Error Resume Next
Set mainForm = Forms(frmname)
If Err.Number <> 0 then
    Set yourSubForm = mainForm.Controls(subfrmname)
    If Err.Number <> 0 then
        Set yourControl = yourSubForm .Form.Controls(ctlname)
        If Err.Number <> 0 then
            Debug.Print yourControl.Value
        Else 
            MsgBox "Cannot find" & subfrmname
        End If
    Else 
        MsgBox "Cannot find" & subfrmname
    End If

Else 
    MsgBox "Cannot find" & frmname
End If
```

Comment: I changed Form() to Forms()

Comment: I also edited the last part of my above question. Still I can't do it correctly. Is it accessing the controls of the form using variable is impossible? thnks!